# In what languages references are non-nullable by default?

Tags: programming-languages, haskell, reference

Out of interest, I want to read about languages that are designed like this. Haskell is one, right?

I am talking about languages that does this, but also has compiler support to catch issues like if it's nullable, then you have to have appropriate cases, handling to compile, etc.

Also is it only a concept that's in functional programming? Does it also exist in some OO languages?

Comment: C++? wrong. Of course you can have null pointers in C++ :D

Comment: @eznme: But you cannot (in a well-defined C++ program) have a null *reference*. A valid reference always refers to an object.

Comment: @Jon Purdy: that's just a confusion of terminology. What is called references in most languages is basically what is called a pointer in C++. C++ references are kind of different.

Comment: @user102008: It's not exactly a confusion so much as just a difference, and anyway I was just playing out of boredom. The typical implementation of C++ references in function arguments is basically as a non-null (and implicitly dereferenced) pointer, as well.

Answer (score 2):

Just to answer the first part of your question, you're right that Haskell doesn't have a special 'null' value that can be of any type.

If you want this behaviour, you have to change the return type of your function. Typically, you use the Maybe type for this, so for example:

```
safeDiv :: Float -> Float -> Maybe Float

safeDiv a b
    | b == 0    = Nothing
    | otherwise = Just (a / b)
```

This says that safeDiv takes two Floats and returns a type `Maybe Float`. In the body of the function, I can then return `Nothing` if b is zero, otherwise I return `Just (a / b)`.

The key point is that your type signature explicitly marks whether your function can return `Nothing` or not, and any caller will be forced to handle the two possible cases in some way.

Haskell does, however, have Exceptions which can be thrown and caught. For pure functions it is preferred to return a Maybe value instead of just throwing an error, but even some Prelude (base library) functions are unsafe. For example, `head`, which returns the first element of a list, throws an error if the list is empty, instead of returning a value wrapped up in Maybe.

Comment: Thanks I see what you mean. Very cool. Also somehow I assume the signature was gonna be like this: safeDiv :: Float, Float -> Maybe Float. Several -> confused me, but that's because I don't know the language. Because to me -> feels like "from to" or "takes and returns", etc.

Comment: Well, there's an easy way to think about this. It's slightly wrong from an implementation point of view I think, but it helps beginners if I say: _all functions only take one argument and return one value_ and _functions can return other functions_. Therefore `Float -> Float -> Maybe Float` is `Float -> (Float -> Maybe Float)`, ie safeDiv takes a Float, and returns another function that takes a Float and returns a Maybe Float.

Comment: This allows you to derive functions from other functions by providing some (but not all) of the arguments. For example: `x = (2*)` is a valid way to define a function that doubles its argument. We give `*` one of its arguments but not the other one.

Comment: Thanks Chris, in your first comment when you said "Therefore Float -> Float -> Maybe Float is Float -> (Float -> Maybe Float), ie safeDiv takes a Float, and returns another function that takes a Float and returns a Maybe Float." is it really like that in the language or just a point of view? Seems very interesting.

Comment: Also do you happen to be a Haskell expert? You seem to know this very well. I find this language very interesting, and can't believe how they thought of these concepts really long ago.

Comment: @Joan: The language basically works that way. Googling "currying" or "partial function application" might help you. Currying a function is turning a function with multiple arguments into a function that takes a single argument and (maybe) returns another function. Functions are curried by default in Haskell. Partial function application is supplying only some of the arguments to a function and getting back a function that takes fewer arguments. Since currying is the default in Haskell, partially applied functions are very common.

Comment: @Joan: I'm not an expert, I've just used it enough to understand most of the most important concepts. The thing about Haskell is that it's as deep as you want it to be. Because it makes creating and passing around functions easy and has a fairly complex type system, there are some very complicated libraries and abstractions out there. But you don't need to understand all of them to do useful things with Haskell.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Btw do you know if Haskell is a fast language, say for real-time games, etc? Is it available on .NET, something like IronHaskell maybe? If not I will still want to learn it.

Comment: Well, there are a few implementations. GHC, the Glasgow Haskell Compiler, produces reasonably fast programs. I'm not sure about games, because I don't know of anyone who's tried to develop a complex game in Haskell.

Comment: There isn't anything available on .Net because it proved impossible to get reasonable performance on the .Net runtime. The .Net runtime makes some assumptions about the languages running on it that Haskell breaks. The big problem is laziness: Haskell delays evaluation by default until a value is actually needed. IIRC, implementing this on .Net absolutely killed performance.

Comment: @Joan Venge: Haskell is reasonnably performant (it's about only 2 times slower than C)... if you program idiomatically. It comes with a full suite of tools to debug and profile the application though. Also, there have been application written in Haskell already, but I do not know of any game. At any rate, the FFI (Foreign Interface) would let you call C routines for rendering if it proved insufficient.

Comment: @Matthieu: I think the major problem is going to be laziness and the performance characteristics of some of the common persistent data structures. Haskell performance is quite good on average (on an amortised basis) but some of its design choices probably make doing hard real-time in it quite difficult.

Comment: Btw what apps are written using Haskell? And using which GUI framework? Winforms for instance?

Comment: @Joan: well, the most widely used GUI bindings in Haskell are to wxWindows and GTK, which are cross-platform GUI libraries. There is a foreign function interface (FFI) that lets you create your own bindings to C libraries, but it may not be worth the pain.

Comment: @chrisdb: That and the "idioms" bit, for a new programmer the paradigm shift will lead to suboptimal code for a while. I should have made it clear, but using Haskell for the first time in a performance sensitive project does not seem a good idea... One should start small!

Comment: Thanks guys, wxWindows is from wxWidgets, right? I imagine it's these things that make it less than ideal. Like I know Unreal Engine 3 also uses wxWidgets and they weren't very user-friendly at all.

Comment: @Joan: yes, I think wxWindows had a rename at some point. Personally, I think it's OK, but for any cross-platform toolkit there's always a cost. Perfect integration on all platforms is hard.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I agree. It's not easy :O

Answer (score 2):

Any of the ML-derived languages (of which Haskell is one) work like this, including SML and F# (although `null` can leak into F# from .NET interop). Scala also generally shuns `null` but the fact that it sits on top of the JVM makes it less strict about it than some other languages.

Answer (score 1):

You will find that Nullable is a matter of definition.

Most languages can be seen to have nullable pointers but not nullable values. Also, many languages provide a special null/nil-object with which variables are initialized automatically; would you count this as nullable?

On the one hand it is a special value distinct from all the values the variable normally holds (e.g. numbers), and is from that perspective the same as if you work with only pointers to numbers (nullable).

On the other hand this null/nil-object is a real object with a real class (in class-based-OO languages) and will understand many messages you send to it like asString(), so since it is a real object it is not a "null" in the strictest sense right?

Comment: Yes but I was asking in the "true" sense of the term. Not sure that's how to describe it but basically, avoiding null checks and getting more compiler support and checks, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Two languages that come to mind which support both the object-oriented paradigm and non-nullable types are (arguably) C++ and (definitely) [Spec#](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/specsharp/).

> *Spec# is a formal language for API contracts (influenced by JML, AsmL, and Eiffel), which extends C# with constructs for non-null types, preconditions, postconditions, and object invariants.* 
> — from the Spec# homepage on Microsoft Research

The latter is probably not in widespread use (if it's used at all). There you get a non-nullable type by suffixing a type with `!` (e.g. `object!` or `string![]!`).

Concerning C++, I'm sure someone clever will find plenty of arguments why C++ should not be mentioned here; being the complex, delicate language that it is, I'm sure that such reasons exist. My argument for mentioning C++ anyway is that apart from pointers (`*`) (which can very well be `0`), C++ also has references (`&`), which have to be initialized to something sensible. The main problem with references is, AFAIK, that they cannot be used for everything. There's probably certain situations, e.g. with memory management or smart pointers, where you cannot get completely rid of pointers.

Finally, you could always try to build your own non-nullable wrapper types, e.g. in C#. Probably like many others, [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) has done so and [blogged about it](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/10/06/non-nullable-reference-types.aspx). It's a workable solution, but such a `NotNull<T>` type can feel a bit bulky since it's not truly integrated into the language, as with Spec#.

Comment: Thanks but from what I heard if you say try to use Spec# assemblies in C#, you would be able to set their types to null, right? Like the runtime itself isn't able to enforce this nor does it have the ability to truly have something as non-nullable. From what I read, it still stores them as null, because the types are still class.

Comment: Also that NotNull, even though tries to do this behavior, will still not be able to save itself from null, right?

Comment: @Joan, **1.** you are correct that Spec#'s non-nullable types are not directly supported by the CLI, but are a "feature" added on top of it by the language itself. Which means that the benefits won't be huge in real-world scenarios because you would likely make heavy use of the Base Class Library, which uses nullable (ie. reference) types everywhere. Still... the language mentioned supports non-nullable references, which is what you asked for. :) **2.** Declaring such a `NotNull<T>` type as a `struct` (value type) would help somewhat, as passing `null` in its place would then not be allowed.

Comment: "which have to be initialized to something sensible" But that's the difficulty. How do you make sure that something is sensible?

Comment: *@user102008*, here's how I see it: What it comes down to is that references are guaranteed to be non-nullable only at compile time, but not necessarily at run-time, basically because nullable pointers exist that can interact with references (along the lines of `T* pv = 0; T& rv = *pv;`). This, IMHO, doesn't change the fact that references are non-nullable by design and intention. The fact that you might be able to (at run-time) initialize them to some nonsense via pointers is a whole other issue. (If something needs fixing, it's pointers, not references!)

Answer (score 1):

C++ has been mentioned. If I were designing a C++ library from scratch (something like Qt, say), I would in fact use pointers versus references at various points in the API to indicate whether the given parameter or return type can be null. Then seeing "*" and "->" wouldn't primarily be a visual indicator that you're dealing with a 'non-local' object -- it would be a reminder that you're dealing with something which might be null, and therefore you had better check whether it is.

Haskell's Maybe type is very simple but it's one of the best parts of the language. Doing things this way in C++ doesn't get you everything, but it gets you something and I think it would be quite helpful. (To briefly recap: if a function parameter is not allowed to be null, checking whether it is at runtime is a distant second-best option: if someone broke the rules and gave you a null, even if you check for it there's still nothing much reasonable you can do in response other than crashing the program with an assert. It's much, much better for the compiler to enforce that it can't be null, and disallow callers from passing one in in the first place.)

(Obviously, if you have a null pointer, you can still blindly dereference it, pass it in, and then get a crash anyways. But at least the fact that you're being forced to dereference (as opposed to passing in the pointer unchanged) is a strong cue that you should be checking for nullness. So it's better than nothing.)

Answer (score 0):

It's true that Haskell doesn't have a special null value for every type, but if you work with actual pointers, which the FFI allows you to do, you can create null pointers.